# Row column names are ignored when using createDataFrame with schema in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Column names in a `Row` are ignored and only columns order is considered when passing schema to `createDataFrame`. Any way to correct this, or is there a different way to pass data to `createDataFrame` that respects column names?

```py
schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField("A", T.StringType(), False),
    T.StructField("B", T.StringType(), False)
])
data = [
    Row(B="b1", A="a1"),
    Row(B="b2", A="a2"),
    Row(B="b3", A="a3"),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df.show()
# +---+---+
# |  A|  B|
# +---+---+
# | b1| a1|
# | b2| a2|
# | b3| a3|
# +---+---+
```

In the above snippet, I would expect that column `A` contains `a1, a2, a3` and column `B` contains `b1, b2, b3`.

I know that I can do `df = spark.createDataFrame([x.asDict(True) for x in data], schema=schema)` but then there is no point in using `Row`.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

My original question is a subcase of the above question.

When using `df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)` for a schema containing a `StructType`, instead of using the column names in the struct Row in data, it only considers the order of the row.

Is there a way to change this (ignore the order, use matching column names)?

In the following example, I would expect to see column AAA contain values AAA1, AAA2, etc. But instead, it will take BBB1, BBB2, etc. because data has BBB in the first place.

```py
    import pyspark.sql.types as T
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F

    schema = T.StructType([
        T.StructField("E", T.StringType(), True),
        T.StructField("C", T.StructType([
            T.StructField("AAA", T.StringType(), True),
            T.StructField("BBB", T.StringType(), True),
            T.StructField("CCC", T.StringType(), True),
            T.StructField("DDD", T.StringType(), True),
        ]), True)
    ])
    data = [
        Row(E="E1", C=Row(BBB="BBB1", DDD="DDD1", CCC="CCC1", AAA="AAA1")),
        Row(E="E2", C=Row(BBB="BBB2", DDD=None, CCC="CCC2", AAA="AAA2")),
        Row(E="E3", C=Row(BBB="BBB3", DDD="DDD3", CCC="CCC3", AAA="AAA3")),
        Row(E="E4", C=None)
    ]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
    df2 = df\
        .withColumn("AAA", F.col("C")["AAA"])\
        .withColumn("BBB", F.col("C")["BBB"])\
        .withColumn("CCC", F.col("C")["CCC"])\
        .withColumn("DDD", F.col("C")["DDD"])
    df2.show()
```

The result of the show is:

```
+---+--------------------+----+----+----+----+
|  E|                   C| AAA| BBB| CCC| DDD|
+---+--------------------+----+----+----+----+
| E1|{BBB1, DDD1, CCC1...|BBB1|DDD1|CCC1|AAA1|
| E2|{BBB2, null, CCC2...|BBB2|null|CCC2|AAA2|
| E3|{BBB3, DDD3, CCC3...|BBB3|DDD3|CCC3|AAA3|
| E4|                null|null|null|null|null|
+---+--------------------+----+----+----+----+
```

*EDITS:*

Changed the order and title to simplify the question.

Comment: why not just `spark.createDataFrame(data)` since you have Row object in data already?

Comment: Because some of the columns in Row might be None but they need a type.
So in the above example, data could be `data = [Row(E=None, C=Row(BBB="B", DDD="D", CCC="C", AAA=None))]` or even `data = [Row(E=None, C=None)]`, so you need to specify the type

Comment: I see, makes sense. 1 thing puzzling me is how did you get the list of Row object. If you are obtaining from dataframe, you supposed to have the schema already.  If you made by hand, you would control the order of the columns and you won't have this question.

Comment: This is all for testing, we are creating dfs to test functions, and when we have a table with many columns, it is a hassle to have to manually order the schema every time. Also, what is the point of having column names in Row if they will be ignored? This started happening in Spark3, Spark2 would not ignore the column names.

Comment: I see.  well, this at least works for smaller dataset.  `df = spark.createDataFrame([x.asDict(True) for x in data], schema=schema)`.  At least, having the column name of the Row object makes sense for `asDict` functionality. Or perhaps you can use `sc.parallelize(data).map(lambda x: x.asDict(True))`

Comment: Thanks, that actually works! It feels wrong though. Same as with a dictionary data, where we consider the key as the column name, I don't understand why Row does not work in the same way.

Comment: I bet it is related to what you touched upon in previous comment, from Spark3.0, Row won't be sorted, it is ordered as it is entered. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Row.html 

(no sorting) sounds like a performance related change.